# 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable." 5

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to make a code about usernames:

```
User=input("type a username with 4 numbers, then 2 letters.")
test=(User.isdigit[0:3])
trial=(User.isaplha[4:5])
if test ==True:
  if trial ==True:
    print("This is a valid username.")
  else:
    print("The last two characters must be numbers.")
else: 
 print("The first four characters must be letters.")
```

I receive this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 2, in 
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `User.isaplha[4:5]` => `User[4:5].isalpha()` don't invent syntax you'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

isdigit() and isalpha() don’t support indexing parameters and if you want to apply these builtin functions on specific substring try indexing your string like

```
test = User[0:3].isdigit()
```

It will work perfectly without any errors

Comment: oh. thanks for the help.